# Unpacking Dictionary tuple values in one go

Tags: python-3.x

```
    for i in range (1):
        first.append(input("firstname"))
        last.append(input("lastname"))
        age.append(input("age"))
        city.append(input("city"))
    print(first, last, age, city)
    
    dicto["first_name"] = first
    dicto["last_name"] = last
    dicto["age"] = age
    dicto["city"] = city
    
'''i get error below   '''
 for i, j, k,l in dicto["first_name"], dicto["last_name"], dicto["age"], dicto["city"]:
        print("My name is {fname}{lname}, I'm {age} old, i live in {city}.".format(fname=i, lname=j, age=k, city=l))
```

In the last for statement i the Value error:not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)
if change
What i want to do is, Access first value of tuple for each key for first iteration and so on.

Comment: You mean list actually not tuple.

Comment: yeah @SorousHBakhtiary

Comment: You may want to restructure your data into a list of dictionaries instead of the other way around

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assumed your code has this structure and your python version is > 3.6. otherwise have to use `OrderedDict` instead of `dict`.

```
first = []
last = []
age = []
city = []

dicto = {}

for i in range(2):
    first.append(input("firstname"))
    last.append(input("lastname"))
    age.append(input("age"))
    city.append(input("city"))


dicto["first_name"] = first
dicto["last_name"] = last
dicto["age"] = age
dicto["city"] = city
```

Then you can zip dictionary's values, and interpolate the unpacked data into f-string:

```
for first, last, age, city in zip(*dicto.values()):
    print(f"My name is {first}{last}, I'm {age} old, i live in {city}.")
```

Comment: FYI, this will not work correctly for python < 3.6 because you could not rely on the order of `values()`

Comment: @MadPhysicist you're right, I've made a change to my post to either use python 3.6 or above or use `Orderdict` instead.

Comment: It's `collections.OrderedDict`

Answer (score -2):

You seem to be confused about what [for-loops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) are actually used for. **Don't** use a [for-loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) if you just want to do something once. Use a [for-loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop), when you want to iterate over something or repeat something multiple times.
In your case, there are endless ways to solve your problem, this basic approach be enough to achieve your goals:

```
print(f"My name is {dicto["first_name"]} {dicto["last_name"]}, I'm {dicto["age"]} years old, i live in {dicto["city"]}.")
```

A little more elegant:

```
fname, lname, age, city = zip(dicto["first_name"], dicto["last_name"], dicto["age"], dicto["city"])
print(f"My name is {fname} {lname}, I'm {age} years old, i live in {city}.")
```

Comment: i want to map whole list to the the keys and then access them later. for the sake of continously adding inputs , I am currently adding single value.

Comment: @Foreverlearner Then there are probably some weird choices in your design. What are you aiming to achieve by doing this?

Comment: you are correct in saying that I made  some weird choices .The whole aim is to learn python , this was part of assignment question , after hours of reading docs ,searching ,reading tutorials I came here for help.Posted my question and went to sleep.And after four hours of sleep I found helpful guidance and solutions.

Comment: @Foreverlearner - from [ask]: "After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments." ;)